# how make responsive shape for dark mode in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, styles, darkmode

i create one shape for all activities but i dont know how make responsive for dark mode.how can i do?

this is my shape
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">     <corners         android:topLeftRadius="25dp"         android:topRightRadius="25dp" />     <solid android:color="@color/white"/> </shape>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make your own color resource (instead of using color/white), and define it to different values in light mode and dark modet

Comment: color night mode did not  exist...i had to make it...thank you...you saved my time